# How to add Bulk users(csv file) to particular group in sharepoint online site and sharepoint server?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

In SharePoint after creating a Group how to add bulk user to that particular SharePoint site.In my sharepoint Under one site collctions i have 5 sites like site1, site2, site3, site4, site5 in that 5 sites i need to add 100 users to only site 3.It is possible..? how to add bulk users to particular site? 
Thank you.

Comment: You can achieve this by using powershell scripts

Comment: Follow this (see step 3): https://techchucker.wordpress.com/2013/09/17/addbulkspusergroups/

Answer (score 1):

You use SharePoint online, so you need to use [PowerShell for SharePoint Online](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161397.aspx) and to cmdlet : [Add-SPOUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161371.aspx)

For you need, i found this post : http://3sharp.com/blog/use-powershell-to-automate-groups-and-users-provisioning-in-sharepoint-online/
It describe how to add user in sharepoint online from a CSV/Excel file

Else

If you dont want to code it ! A full script from the Office Gallery (it use the Client SharePoint Object Model)
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-to-add-users-to-1d3e69f9

Hope this help you